# How to do multiple imputation on Julia?

Tags: julia, imputation

I've found the package Impute.jl but it's only able to use these simple methods:

- drop: remove missing.
- locf: last observation carried forward
- nocb: next observation carried backward
- interp: linear interpolation of values in vector
- fill: replace with a specific value or a function...

There seems not to exist any advanced "multiple imputation" method.
How can use more advanced methods when I have several variables?
Such as: fully conditional specification (mice), bayesian methods, random forest, multilevel, nested imputation, censored data, categorical data, survival data...

I don't mean creating my own code but finding any Julia package able to do it automatically. Other software do have it (R, Python, Stata, SAS…).

Answer (score 1):

See the [Imputation module of `BetaML`](https://sylvaticus.github.io/BetaML.jl/stable/Imputation.html).

It includes imputation for tabular data using Gaussian Mixture Models, Random forests or any other ML model with a `fit!`/`predict` interface.

It includes imputations of multiple columns, optionally with multiple imputations and multiple "passages" trough the dataset to impute.

(*disclaimer: I'm the author...*)